# Firestore issue : CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, androidx

I am getting the error below when running my project after installing firestore dependencies. What should I do?

> Note:
>   C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 79495 > 65536)
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:  The number of method references in a .dex file
>   cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html    at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
>   complete  at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)  at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
>     ... 34 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException:
>   Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (#
>   methods: 79495 > 65536)   at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)   at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)   ... 36 more
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
>
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>   >      The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   >      Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5m 31s [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize
>   the Java bytecode.
>       To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
>       To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code Finished with
>   error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't enabled multidex then go to

/android/app/build.gradle and add

`multiDexEnabled true`

In defaultConfig

It should look like this:

```
defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.chat_app_flutter_firebase"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            //Enable multidex by adding this line 

            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you that worked. How did you figure it out ? I am asking so I can try to help myself in the future.

Comment: Had faced same issue a while before so I knew 